# Как проверить ячейку на None?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

Сохраняю содержимое таблицы. Если ячейка пустая то он заносит в таблицу None
как это перехватить что бы если None то в ячейку ничего не записывалось?

```
def save_file(self):
    filename = (QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Сохранить', '', ".xls(*.xls)"))
    wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wbk.add_sheet("схема", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    self.s_f(sheet)
    wbk.save(filename)

def s_f(self, sheet):
    for currentColumn in range(self.table.columnCount()):
        for currentRow in range(self.table.rowCount()):

            my_icon = str(self.table.item(currentRow, currentColumn))
            sheet.write(currentRow, currentColumn, my_icon)
```

Comment: вероятно не стоит `str()`  со всем подряд вызывать. Попробуйте: `if item is not None: sheet.write(...)`

Comment: Без str ругается. Пробовал все равно None печатает.

Comment: Вы сначала на None проверьте, а только  потом str() вызывайте (если ожидаемое использование API в данном случае).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-то типа:

```
my_icon = self.table.item(currentRow, currentColumn)
sheet.write(currentRow, currentColumn, str(my_icon) if my_icon is not None else '')
```

Comment: вот так работает спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
sheet.write(currentRow, currentColumn, '' if my_icon is None else str(my_icon))
```

Comment: Да так понятнее )